# Maximum of stopping times is not a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stopping-times

Is the maximum of two stopping times a stopping time? I wrote

$$\{max(\tau, \sigma) \le t\} = \{\tau \le t\} \cap \{\sigma \le t\} \in \mathcal F_t$$

Because both $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are stopping times. In my book there is written that it isn't though. Can you tell me where the error is?

Comment: The maximum of two stopping times is again a stopping as you just showed. Which book are you reading?

Comment: @StefanHansen thank you, I had actually read the solution of the book wrong (it was a double negation! :D). So the book agrees it is a stopping time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read the book solution incorrectly. Indeed the maximum of two stopping times is a stopping time, as I showed in the question.

Comment: well do you mind giving a proof then? What is the purpose of this question otherwise?

Comment: @MarineGalantin The proof is in the question. The intersection of two events belonging to a sigma algebra is also in the sigma algebra, which proves that the maximum of the two stopping times is indeed a stopping time